# Heat pump running on Heat and fan or Cool and fan

Tags: heating, cooling, heat

We just had heat pumps installed. I know that you cannot have the heat and the cool going at the same time. But can you have a head in fan mode and another head in heat or cool mode?

---

Sorry for the confusion. Only one heat pump outside, but there are 3 heads inside. We understand that we cannot put heat and cool on at the same time, but trying to determine whether you can put it in heat and fan or cool and fan. They can all run in just fan mode, but if one is in heat mode and 2 are in fan mode how does that effect the unit, since it is not pumping cold? How would I find out if a unit is capable of doing that?

Comment: If there are separate controls, I can't see why you _couldn't_ have each one set to run differently. By "head", and you referring to the individual outdoor units?

Comment: This sounds like a mini-split system where you have one outdoor unit (the actual heat pump) and several, usually up to 4 indoor head units.  The OP is correct in that the outdoor unit can only be in heating or cooling mode. Whether they can be run in "fan only" mode would depend upon the unit.  RTFM.

Comment: OP did say "heat pumps" (plural), so I made an assumption, even if it was a bad one...